# How to build a 2D board using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a 2D game board (like a chess board) and each square has a value inside (Int = 1). This board has initially 9 squares (3x3).

Then I need a player that starts at the center of the bard and when I move the player to the edge of the board, it expands.

Example: The player reaches the [3,3] square and the board grows to a 4x4 board.

Also, when as the player moves it will change the value inside each square, from 0 to 1.

This is what I have so far

```
//Variables to get the player position and expand the board
let initialSize = 3
var newValueX = 0
var newValueY = 0
var newPlayerX = 0
var newPlayerY = 0
//Board
var board= [[Int]]()

struct Player {
    var X = 0
    var Y = 0
}

func expandBoard (){
    for k in 0..<9{
        for i in 0..<initialSize {
            for j in 0..<initialSize {
                array[k].append([i,j])
            }
        }
    }
}

func movePlayer(){
    var player = Player() //this goes to viewDidLoad
    player.X = newPlayerX
    player.Y = newPlayerY
}
```

An example of the pretended output:
Player moved to [0,3] and changed the square value from 1 to 0.

How can I do this correctly?

EDIT:

I have

```
class Array2D<T> {
    var columns = 1//: Int
    var rows = 1//: Int

    var array: Array<T?>

     init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.columns = columns
        self.rows = rows

        array = Array<T?>(repeating: nil, count:rows * columns)
    }

    subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
        get {
            return array[(row * columns) + column]
         }
        set(newValue) {
            array[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
     }
}

func move(PX: Int, PY: Int){
    if (board[PX, PY] == true){
        moveCount += 1
        board[PX, PY] = false
    }
    if (PX == board.rows.magnitude){
        board.rows += 1
    }
    if (PY == board.columns.magnitude){
        board.columns += 1
    }
}
```

And when I run i get "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" on line (return array[(row * columns) + column]) from the subscript.
Any Idea how can I fix this?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: What should happen if the the user on (0,0) wants to move to (-1,-1), is that allowed?

Comment: yes going from (0,0) to (-1,-1) is allowed

Comment: @TotumusMaximus my problem is how do I build the board that has the requirements I described.

Comment: @user3664043 stackoverflow is not made to do your work for you. We love to help you out with specific problems you might have though.

Comment: @user3664043 I'd recommend breaking it into smaller parts and trying to solve each one-by-one. Then if you need help solving those, ask here.

Comment: Maybe I described a bit too much and came out wrong, all I need help is with defining the board. Should I use a bidimensional array, a dictionary or is there any other way?

Comment: A two-dimensional array for your board will not easily support having (-1,-1) as the player coordinates. What does that even mean?

Comment: @Gereon It means the player can move an infinite amount of times in any direction, but I guess I can work with only positive numbers. Now I'm trying a dictionary like var board = [Int: (Int, Int)]() if it works i'll post here

Comment: Added new Information, I think I'm done once I fix that Index out of range problem

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SpriteKit, which have an element called 'Tile Map' which meets your requirements, [here is a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/137216/whats-new-spritekit-ios-10-look-tile-maps) that can help.

Comment: although I don't need a visual representation for this one, I found the tutorial fantastic! Will try it asap. ty

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` would be another simple choice if you don't want use the SpriteKit.